# Create a new column in pandas with the conditions function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

So I have a dataset with the column of 'world rank uni'. The idea is to create a new column 'Rank lvl' which:

- If the `world_rank` is between 1 and 100, then "First Tier Top University"
- If the `world_rank` is between 101 and 200, then "Second Tier Top University"
- If the `world_rank` is between 201 and 300, then "Third Tier Top University"
- Else："Other Top University"

So I wrote a function:

```
def rank_lvl(group):
if group['world_rank'] >= 100:
    group['Rank_Level'] = 'First Tier Top University'
if group['world_rank'] >= 200 and group['world_rank'] <= 101:
    group['Rank_Level'] = 'Second Tier Top University'
if group['world_rank'] > 300 and group['world_rank'] >= 201:
    group['Rank_Level'] = 'Third Tier Top University'
else:
    group['Rank_Level'] = 'Other Top University'
return group
```

Which I want to apply on ma dataframe:

```
df.apply(rank_lvl).head()
```

But I receive an error which tells me:

```
KeyError: ('world_rank', 'occurred at index world_rank')
```

Don't really understand what is wrong. I am going to be vary glad for an explenation :)

Comment: In fact: `group['world_rank'] >= 200 and group['world_rank'] <= 101` never be True

Comment: The function is applied over columns, not rows: `apply(rank_lvl, axis=1)`, to test multiple conditions use `elif` after the first `if`, to work with apply the function should `return` the label not the dataframe row. Setting `group['Rank_Level']` inside the function is not the usual approach and will confuse `apply`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) from numpy:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Minimal setup
np.random.seed(2022)
df = pd.DataFrame({'world_rank': np.random.randint(1, 500, 10)})

condlist = [df['world_rank'] <= 100,
            (df['world_rank'] > 100) & (df['world_rank'] <= 200),
            (df['world_rank'] > 201) & (df['world_rank'] <= 300)]

choicelist = ['First Tier Top University',
              'Second Tier Top University',
              'Third Tier Top University']

default = 'Other Top University'

df['Rank_Level'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist, default)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   world_rank                  Rank_Level
0         382        Other Top University
1         221   Third Tier Top University
2         174  Second Tier Top University
3         113  Second Tier Top University
4         178  Second Tier Top University
5         498        Other Top University
6         241   Third Tier Top University
7         440        Other Top University
8         345        Other Top University
9          19   First Tier Top University
```

**Update**

You can also use [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

```
df['Rank_Level'] = pd.cut(df['world_rank'], bins=[0, 100, 200, 300, np.inf],
                          labels=choicelist + [default])
```

Comment: Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Basically I was looking for the answer why it doesn't work, not for a different solution :)
It turns out, thanks to Michael Szczesny that I had to set axis=1, to columns instead of default rows.

Comment: Ok I understand. However avoir apply when you can and conditionnally statements in particular when you have a large dataframe.